# Debugging Random Reboots in Android

Tags: android

So I'm trying to debug why my phone is randomly rebooting (and hoping it isn't my app). The only pattern I've noticed is that occasionally when try and unlock it, the phone is off and I have to hold the power button to turn it back on.

I believe this started happening while I was writing an app widget, but can't be sure.

adb bugreport doesn't reveal anything interesting, no kernel panics anyway

```
------ LAST KMSG (/proc/last_kmsg) ------
*** /proc/last_kmsg: No such file or directory

------ LAST PANIC CONSOLE (/data/dontpanic/apanic_console) ------
*** /data/dontpanic/apanic_console: No such file or directory

------ LAST PANIC THREADS (/data/dontpanic/apanic_threads) ------
*** /data/dontpanic/apanic_threads: No such file or directory
```

Logcat doesn't persist past a reboot, so I wrote a small service that is writing it to disk for me now (we'll see if I find anything there)

Has anyone else dealt with this before? How do you go about debugging this type of issue normally?

My phone is a gsm galaxy nexus running 4.1.2, but I also noticed it on 4.1.1

Comment: how did you find out what was causing the issue?? I am having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this... set up 'acra' - The Android crash notifier [1]. Its open source and available on github [2]  If your application ever crashes and causes android to crash, the logs from acra can help debug the situation.

[1] - http://acra.ch/

[2] - https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Comment: I've used ACRA before but it doesn't really help in this situation, the entire OS is crashing, not my app

Comment: I see. Well if ACRA does not report any error, its probably not your app. Are there any tombstone entries on your phone - https://sites.google.com/a/itspaclub.com/www/android-debug/7-how-to-debug-native-code/7-6-android-tombstones. How to read them - http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:android:crashlog

Comment: You'd be surprised. I found a bug in 2.3 where a misconfigured xml file in my app caused the system to crash and reboot.

Comment: Does ACRA not report those ? I think the reason may be that the error occurred much before ACRA.init() was ever called. Maybe the dalvik VM gave up after trying to parse AndroidManifest.xml ? Still there may be a tombstone for these crashes.